# Класс устанавливающий курсор ожидания и автоматически сбрасывающий его

Tags: c#, winforms

Создал вот такой класс:

```
class CursorEx: IDisposable
{
    public CursorEx()
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

Использую вот так:

```
public void Method()
{
    new CursorEx();
    //Здаесь что-то выполняется
}
```

Подразумевается, что после выполнения метода, вызовется метод Dispose() и курсор установится на дефолтный.
Могут ли быть какие-то варианты, когда произойдет сбой?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Во-первых, вы забыли вызвать `Dispose`. Для этого следует использовать `using`:

```
using (new CursorEx()) {
    // что-то выполняется
}
```

На сборку мусора полагаться нельзя, она вызывается недетерминированно в любой момент после пропадания объекта из области видимости.

Во-вторых, вы не восстанавливаете исходный курсор. Если какая-то функция изменяет курсор, а затем вызывает функцию, которая тоже изменяет курсор, то курсор будет восстановлен уже после возврата из первой функции:

```
using (new CursorEx()) {
    using (new CursorEx()) {
        // что-то выполняется
    }
    // курсор уже восстановлен
}
// курсор должен был быть восстановлен здесь
```

Вам следует сохранять текущий курсор в конструкторе и восстанавливать его в `Dispose`.

В-третьих, можно избавиться от лишнего объекта в памяти, если заменить класс на структуру.

Итого:

```
public struct CursorWaiter : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Cursor _originalCursor;

    public CursorWaiter (Cursor newCursor = null)
    {
        _originalCursor = Cursor.Current;
        Cursor.Current = newCursor ?? Cursors.WaitCursor;
    }

    public void Dispose ()
    {
        Cursor.Current = _originalCursor;
    }
}
```

Из комментариев: этот код рассчитан на то, что программист будет использовать тип только с помощью `using`, не будет уничтожать объект по несколько раз, не будет копировать и т.п. Если есть сомнения в этом, то нужно добавить проверку на повторный вызов `Dispose` (с помощью отдельного флага или обнуления `_originalCursor`), а также заменить класс на структуру для избавления он возможности копирования или вовсе скрыть тип за методом с лямбдой.

Comment: Добавил пример реализации.

Comment: А зачем структура? При использовании `using` объект всё равно будет боксирован для вызова `Dispose`. А семантики структуры у него всё равно нет.

Comment: @VladD Не будет боксирован: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2412981/if-my-struct-implements-idisposable-will-it-be-boxed-when-used-in-a-using-statem

Comment: @VladD Структура — чтобы не заморачиваться с `GC.SuppressFinalize(this)` или дополнительными проверками/обнулениями ради избавления от двойного вызова. Строго говоря, семантика в пролёте, да. Тут расчёт на то, что паттерн использования будет один и только один.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, там о вызове `obj.Dispose()`, а `using` [использует](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664736%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) `((IDisposable)obj).Dispose()`. [Эрик](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/14/to-box-or-not-to-box-that-is-the-question.aspx) пишет "the disposed resource is in fact not boxed in our implementation of C#. The compiler has an optimization" => не гарантировано.

Comment: `GC.SuppressFinalize` и прочие радости полной имплементации `IDisposable`, как я понимаю, не нужны. Максимум флаг, чтобы защититься от повторного вызова `Dispose`.

Comment: @VladD Если в компиляторе пропадёт оптимизация, код не сломается. А пока оптимизация есть, можно ей пользоваться. Ну, скажем, что `x * 2` будет оптимизировано в `x << 1` — это тоже никто не гарантирует. Но нормальные люди `x << 1` не пишут, когда умножают целые на два. / Я же говорю: это для краткости. Мне проще заменить class на struct, а не писать код с флагами, проверками и прочим. / И таки `GC.SuppressFinalize` лучше вызывать, потому что сборщику мусора будет меньше работы. Некоторые классы его вообще в конструкторе вызывают.

Comment: "SuppressFinalize should only be called by a class that has a finalizer" ([отсюда](http://stackoverflow.com/a/151244/276994)).

Comment: А флаг всё равно нужен, т. к. что для структуры, что для класса можно вызвать `Dispose` несколько раз вручную.

Comment: @VladD Ой, да, туплю. / Мой код рассчитан на воспитанного программиста, который будет использовать тип только в `using`. Если есть опасения в обратном, то надо писать более дуракоустойчивый код, да.

Comment: Можно сделать класс/структуру приватной и заврапить: `void WithCursor(Cursor c, Action a) { using (new CursorEx(c)) a(); }`. Хотя конечно оверхэд на лямбду и всё такое.

Comment: @VladD С лямбдой не так красиво будет, имхо. Хотя и на извращённое использование `using` некоторые плюются, в том числе Эрик, так что вопрос вкуса. Так или иначе, обновил ответ.

Comment: Да, некрасиво, и (маргинально) менее эффективно. Возможно, это проблема синтаксиса: если бы в C# были [trailing closures](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH11-ID102), выглядело бы неотличимо от `using`.

Comment: Вопрос правильности и «чистоты» использования `IDisposable` как-то [обсуждался на en.SO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10316418/276994).

Answer (score 2):

Конечно. Это вообще хоть раз сработало? Вы неверно пользуетесь сборкой мусора, .NET работает **сосвсем** не так, как C++.

Объект будет уничтожен не в конце метода, а когда захочется сборщику мусора. Поскольку у вас нет на него ссылок, то он может вообще быть уничтожен сразу после создания. А метод `Dispose` вообще не будет вызван автоматически, `IDisposable` для рантайма никакого специального значения не имеет.

Делайте так:

```
public void Method()
{
    using (new CursorEx())
    {
        //Здаесь что-то выполняется
    }
}
```

И обязательно разберитесь со временем жизни объектов в .NET, без этого никуда.

Comment: Насчёт времени жизни объектов и управления им, посмотрите, например, [тут](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15360/Implementing-IDisposable-and-the-Dispose-Pattern-P).

Comment: Спасибо, почитаю про время жизни подробнее.
Что интересно, все написанное мной срабатывало. Возможно мне просто везло.

Comment: @xlmax Оно бы гарантированно работало в C++. :) Можно было бы просто написать `CursorEx c;` в начале функции.

Comment: @xlmax: Не могло работать: вы не вызывали `Dispose`! Так что у вас кто-то другой сбрасывает курсор.